# Operator overloading for +

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cube
{
    int w,l,d;
public:
    Cube(int w, int l, int d) : w(w), l(l), d(d){}
    int getWidth() const {return w;}
    int getLength() const {return l;}
    int getDepth() const {return d;}
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream&os, const Cube& c)
{
    os << "( " << c.getWidth() << ", " << c.getLength() << ", " << c.getDepth() << ")";
    return os;
}

Cube operator+ (Cube& c1, Cube& c2)
{
    int n = c1.getWidth() * c1.getDepth() * c1.getLength();
    int d = c2.getWidth() * c2.getDepth() * c2.getLength();
    int t = n + d;
    return Cube(t);
}

int main()
{
    Cube c1(3,5,9), c2(2,1,4);
    cout << c1 << endl;
    cout << c2 << endl;
    cout << "Total Volume: " << c1 + c2;
}
```

In my operator+ there are some mistakes which I couldn't find out.
The operator overloading for ( + ) should add up two cubes which will result in summing up of the volume of both cubes.

What should I do to my operator overloading for ( + ) ?

Comment: You don't have a constructor that takes a single parameter for `Cube(t)`, so I guess the "mistake" is you forgot to write one?

Comment: Look at the `return Cube(t);` What are you returning in this case? You'r `constructor` is of the form `Cube(int, int, int)`

Comment: It it's actually a cube, and not just a general cuboid, why does it have 3 separate values to represent width, length and depth? It just needs one, since the definition of a Cube demands that they are all the same.

Comment: What if I am not allowed to change the constructor ? What should I do to my operator overloading (+) ? @WhozCraig

Comment: @user3141403: Change it to call the constructor that `Cube` actually has. The one with 3 arguments.

Comment: @user3141403 for one, take Benjamin's advise. A true cube has only one significant dimension value, and its use for all three dimensions (l/w/h). If you want the addition to be by *volume* you need to add the two cube volumes, then take the cube-root to store of the resulting `Cube` size (leaving the problem of storing an irrational cube-root in an `int` to you to solve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total volume of both cubes with operator +, you should return int instead of Cube object, you can't possibly use cout with Cube anyway. You can do this

```
int operator+ (Cube& c1, Cube& c2) {
    int n = c1.getWidth() * c1.getDepth() * c1.getLength();
    int d = c2.getWidth() * c2.getDepth() * c2.getLength();
    return n + d; 
}
```

Comment: also, take the arguments by const reference, since they are not being modified

Comment: If you're going to use int all the way, just return int